# Best practices: How to go through an array in C?

Tags: c

---EDIT--- The array was previously initialized as a pointer (*arr).

For a problem I´m trying to solve, I need to go through an array of variable size and started using this loop:

```
int arr[] = {3, 5, 10, -2, -1, -3}; // Just an example
int i = 0;

while(arr[i]) {

    //do something
    i++;

}
```

It seems that after going through the array I initiliazed, the code finds some random values stored in memory and keeps counting, even though the array I´m trying to work with has long been passed.

How could I avoid this?

Best regards!

Comment: You have to store the length of the array *somewhere*, your approach just iterates past the bounds of the array

Comment: Why do you think that reading behind your array (which in itself is undefined behaviour and therefor evil) should result in ending the loop? Or even after reading the last legal? I do not get the question I think.

Comment: Maybe you explain how you yourself believe that the code works. Especially explain  how the loop condition is evaluated.

Comment: The code you show in the question is not valid C. `int *arr` declares a pointer, which means it should be initialized by one value, and that value should be an address. The compiler should have warned you that your initializers have too many values and that an address is needed. If it did not, you should enable warnings in your compiler. If it did, you should pay attention to them. If this is not code you actually tried to compile, you should show real code. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: The fact that “the code finds some random values stored in memory” suggests you actually executed some code, but it is not what is shown in the example. You cannot expect us to debug code we cannot see.

Comment: While iterating over the array you didn't provide any upper bound, this `while(arr[i])` condition will always be true since `arr`, `i` has been initialized with no upper bound for iteration.

Comment: Might be useful to point out that the term "variable sized array" has a technical meaning in C that you can read about [at Wikipedial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99).

Comment: @EricPostpischil The random values found by the code, are the ones that the loop finds in memory after it goes through the values stored in the array. I was looking for a good way to end the loop, which was given in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *arr` is not the array.

`int` is not the type which should be used as the index. Use `size_t` instead

## Array

`int arr[50];` <- this the array

you can get the size of the array dividing its size by the size of  the element.

## pointer

`int *ptr;` it only references the int object. You **cant** get the size of the allocated memory by dividing size of the pointer by size of reference object

Comment: Perfect! That is what I was looking for!